# Running servers in the same room with a washing machine

Tags: hosting, rack

Just moved into a place with a giant utility room. Was planning on sticking a couple of racks I use to host stuff in there but the washer / dryer is in there.

I've heard that the bleach used to wash clothes breakdowns and the air in there would be bad for computers (corrosive to metal)? Is there any truth to this? What would you recommend?

On a side note the heat issue in that room will not be a problem.

Comment: Not sure about the bleach... but I'd be very hesitant to put systems in a room with heat (dryer) and high humidity (washer and dryer).  That just seems very unwise for the long term health of the systems.

Comment: dryer lint => clogged fans

Comment: You're honestly not understand how bad of an Idea this is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find a way to create a smaller room inside that one. There are many problems in putting all together:

- Heath and humidity problems from the dryer/washer.
- Possible corrosive chemicals and residues (soap, bleach, lint, etc). It all gets in the air.
- Electricity problems (electrical motors have huge effects on the electrical quality of a circuit) that will force you to have a decent UPS + fuse boxes and etc.

If you create a smaller room you can make it have better air/temperature and electricity installing a second circuit or putting measures between the *dirt* energy from the outside and the *clean* energy on the inside. It also helps on security, since there must be heavy traffic of people on the "laundry" area.

Comment: Regarding the chemicals are there different kinds of detergents which would be better than standard stuff?

Comment: Washers and dryers put a lot of moisture into the air.  The moisture alone is enough to cause serious problems.  On top of that, bleach is very corrosive.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very bad idea, a utility room with washers and dryers will not have proper HVAC. Dryers put off massive amounts of heat, I don't see how you think it won't be an issue. We also have to think about corrosive chemicals that will be in the air. Also Electrical motors play hell on the circuit, making stable power impossible. As far as security, how many people will have access to your servers? How many might pull out cords to see what they do? There must be a better place to put your servers...

Comment: run the servers out of my house and everyone who lives here works for the company so security is not an issue. its really an issue of space. regarding the circuit issue we're going to have separate circuits running the machines down there instead of the ones that run the washer / dryer.

Answer (score 0):

Top of my list would be getting a separate power circuit for the computers - washing machines/dryers can make the line very noisy. And, of course, you were planning to install good quality UPS anyway?